# numberOfLines in UITextview?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uilabel

UIlabel has numberOfLines property. It says my string has 2 lines. But when I use UItextview , I want to split the number of lines based on length of text in UITextview. How can I do it? UIlabel automatically splits, but UITextview does not do it.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView inherently allows multiple lines of text. You just separate your lines with the "/n" character and you're done.

Comment: hi,thanks..but i want to split no of lines based on length of UITextview,how can i do it?any help?

Comment: Edit the question with more detail regarding what you would like to achieve and more people would be able to help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The lines should be separated by "\r"

Here's an example:

```
lblNeedSubscription = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[lblNeedSubscription setNumberOfLines:0];  // allows as many lines as needed
[lblNeedSubscription setText:@"To access content\ryou need to be a paid subscriber"];
```