# Two columns of text in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

Is it possible to organize text into two columns with just a UITextView? If not, how can I calculate the height for a given string of text?

Comment: Check this link it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818590/numberoflines-in-uitextview

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I will be getting the text from an external source, so I don't have a chance to put "\r" or "\n" and whatnot.

Comment: i dont understand by `height for a given string of text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString has metric functions such as

`sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`

that you will need to use. Actually I usually use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`, after creating a `CGSizeMake(columnWidth, FLT_MAX)` which is then used for the result also - with FLT_MAX as height, only width is being constrained. The resulting CGSize returned will tell you the actual height.

I think that with that in mind it will be much easier for you to use two `UITextViews` and to break the text into two sections.

Comment: Agreed. I would want to break the text at a halfway point, so how can I figure out the text in a given height of a UITextView?

Comment: I would probably first determine the height of the total then loop through a build of the first column adding words (determined by spaces, you could easily make an array of all the words in the string) until you arrive at a height approximately half the total. Second column is the rest of the words. But like most iOS problems where the solution you come up with seems a bit cumbersome I bet there is a smarter way.

Comment: Wait, if both columns are the same width, I can just take half or the string. Duh >.<

Answer (score -1):

A single UITextView can only display one column.
To get the height, create an offscreen UITextView and then try something like:

```
myTextView.text = theText;
theTextHeight = [myTextView contentSize].height; // in points
```